# Why "from . import re" fails but "import re; from . import re" succeeds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm playing with Python's relative import and the following result (with **Python 3.7.3** on Debian 10.12) surprises me:

```
$ python3
>>> from . import re
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 're' from '__main__' (unknown location)
>>> import re
>>> re
<module 're' from '/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py'>
>>> from . import re
>>> re
<module 're' from '/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py'>
>>>
```

Why `from . import re` succeeds after `import re`? What's happening?

---

##### UPDATE:

**Python 3.8.2** on macOS 13.2 gives different result. Maybe a **Python 3.7** bug?

```
>>> from . import re
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
>>> import re
>>> re
<module 're' from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/
                   Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py'>
>>> from . import re
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
>>> re
<module 're' from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/
                   Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py'>
>>>
```

Comment: That shouldn't actually work, even after the `import re`. It should give an `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. You're likely running on a weirder setup than what you've shown.

Comment: no weird setup. it's a normal debian system.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior on a totally fresh Debian 10.12 VM with the default Python installation. Very peculiar. Image used: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/10.12.0/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: I found that Python version 3.7.4 exhibits this behavior, but version 3.7.5 does not.

Comment: Does Python not simply ignore `from . import re` because `re` is already imported?

Comment: @Guimoute No - generally if you import a name that already exists, the new value overwrites the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, a bug.

Going to the [python changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html#id152), for version 3.8.0 you can see the following:

> [bpo-37409](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/81590): Ensure explicit relative imports from interactive sessions and scripts (having no parent package) always raise ImportError, rather than treating the current module as the package. Patch by Ben Lewis.

So if you don't want that, make sure to use a python with version greater than 3.8.0